# Why one or both Android smartphones turn screen on when I stack them?

Tags: screen

Sometimes when I lay an Android smartphone atop of another one (both sleeping, screen off), one or both of the devices turn on screen (as if I pressed the power button).

Why does this happen? NFC is off on both devices.

Comment: Might have to do with the magnetic unlock feature try it with a magnet to verify it does the same thing like a kitchen magnet not anything too strong

Comment: Yes, magnet wakes up both smathphones if I wave it near the device in a particular way.

Comment: Found disabler: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2621807